# TableView didn't show data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created two `UITableViews` to make a `drawerController`.

1. The left `UITableView` isn't showing data correctly.
2. The `tableHeaderView` has separator in the background.
3. `PageControl's` x position is moving half screen width in difference then I set it.

There is my project in [Github](https://github.com/gshushu/-0).

There is mainView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *mainTableView=[MainTableView createMainView];
    self.mainTableView=mainTableView;
    self.mainTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, yScreenWidth, yScreenHeight);
    mainTableView.delegate=self;
    mainTableView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:mainTableView];

    UITableView *leftMenuTableView=[LeftMenuTableView createLeftMenuView];
    self.leftMenuTableView=leftMenuTableView;
    _leftMenuTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    leftMenuTableView.delegate=self;
    leftMenuTableView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:leftMenuTableView];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    UIButton *leftBar=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 44, 44)];
    NSString *bundleStr=@"Resource.bundle/";
    NSString *imagePath=[bundleStr stringByAppendingString:@"leftIcon.png"];
    [leftBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftBar addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeftMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view insertSubview:leftBar aboveSubview:mainTableView];
}
```

There is `dataSource` method:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == _mainTableView) {
        return TryTBData.count;
    }else if (tableView ==_leftMenuTableView){
        return 13;
    }
    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *mainCellID=@"main_cell";
    static NSString *leftCell=@"reuseidentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    if (tableView == _mainTableView) {
        cell=[_mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mainCellID];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mainCellID];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=TryTBData[indexPath.row];
    }else if (tableView == _leftMenuTableView){
        cell=[_leftMenuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:leftCell];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:leftCell];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=@"22";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

`mainTableView` show the correct data, but `leftMenuTableView` isn't showing any  data.
[image: run picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `[self addMenuTable];` in LeftMenuTableView.m.

You are creating your `LeftMenuTableView` object and then adding another table view on top of it.

If you use the Debug View Hierarchy feature in Xcode, you can see all the cells with "22" in them behind another view that's blocking them.